# Form with checkboxes getting all checked checkboxes

Tags: php, foreach

I am trying to make a random tournament generator, where I can select names from a list with checkboxes and then randominze them into a different order.

I have the following form:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo ROOT ?>HomeController/createTournament/" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <div class="form-group">
        <label for="participants">Select participants</label><br>
            <?php foreach($players as $p): ?>
                <input type="checkbox" name="participants" value="<?php echo $p['name'];?>"> <?php echo $p['name'];?><br>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" name="create">Show participants</button>
</form>
```

This form show's a checkbox and behind the checkbox the name of the participant.

This is my method:

```
 public function createTournament() {
    if(isset($_POST["create"])) {
        $participants = $_POST['participants'];
    } 
    include('app/views/showTournament.php');
}
```

That means I am saving the checked ones into $participants, right?

In the file showTournament, I know have access to $partipants.
I try to var_dump $particpants and it shows me:

```
string(6) "Onlyoneselected name"
```

So I tried a foreach, to get ALL of the selected names.

```
 <?php 
foreach($participants as $p) {
    echo $p;
}
;?>
```

The foreach isn't showing anything, but the file has access to $participants. I want all the names on my screen, so I can start randomizing them. What do I do wrong?

Comment: Change `name="participants"` to `name="participants[]"`.

Comment: Of course, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="participants"
```

This line here is the root of your problems.

Because every checkbox has the same name, the value of `$_POST['participants']` gets overridden for each checkbox in the list.

If you change that snippet to:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="participants[]"
```

Then `$_POST['participants']` becomes an array of all checked values.

Answer (score 1):

You need multiple checkbox values.

And therefore, HTML name of the input should be multiple (array)

`<input type="checkbox" name="participants"` will return string, only latest submitted value.

`<input type="checkbox" name="participants[]"` will return array of all submitted values.

So, replacing `name="participants"` to `name="participants[]"` will work.